# Combinations with repetitions, equality among to solutions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

The textbook I'm reading says the number of integer solutions for
$$x1+x3+x5+x7=5 \text{ where } x1,x3,x5,x7>0$$
is equal to
$$y1+y3+y5+y7=1, \text{ where } y1,y3,y5,y7>= 0$$

This connection is not obvious to me. Can anyone explain why they are equal and why all of the sudden the equality sign appears on the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each of the numbers have to be an integer, $x > 0$ is equivalent to saying $x \geq 1$. Now to get positive solution, we do this simple trick. Let $x_i=y_i+1$. Then the first  equation above becomes equivalent to the 2nd equation.

Comment: Doesn't the first equation already imply a positive solution? Why is the conversion necessary? Also, if x>0 is equivalent to saying x>=1, why is it x>=0 for the second equation?

Comment: No, some solutions of the first equation might have a 0 x coordinate. For instance $x_1=5$, rest of them $0$ is a solution, but it's not a solution that you want. Since we did the trick, now after we get $y_i's$ even if some of them are $0$, still $x_i$ being equal to $y_i+1$ will be atleast 1, and then we have positive solutions for the original equation.

Comment: Thank you. So the limit for the second equation, are you just allowed to add the equality like that?

Comment: Yes, here we are looking at all non negative solutions without restriction, so we can do this. Hope this helps.

Comment: @voldemort Your analysis is correct, except I think you want $x_i = y_i+1$ or $y_i = x_i - 1$. YOu may want to correct it.

Comment: @user44197: Thanks.